# *UPDATED*: Issue with writing over tkinter postscript file

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, save, turtle-graphics

**EDIT:** Okay, I guess what I was asking before is not possible as the turtle canvas is not a text object. However, I have now settled for creating a postscript file when the program starts and I do that with the following function:

```
def save():
   cnv = getscreen().getcanvas()
   hel = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = '.ps')
   global fev
   fev = cnv.postscript(file = hel, colormode = 'color')
```

This is called in the beginning of the program. Then, as the user presses presses a tkinter "Save" button, the following is executed:

```
def savefirst():
   open('fev.ps', 'a+b')
```

This is supposed to save any changes to the canvas to the postscript file created in the beginning by the user, kind of like in a word processor. However, **it does not do that for some reason**, and I know this because whenever I create a file, draw on the canvas, press the "Save" button, then open the saved file, it is still blank. ***Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?***

Comment: If it's not possible to save the turtle canvas directly, you could save all the user input, then when you next start the program, replay that input first before allowing additional input.

Comment: @TomDalton Okay, I am fine with that, but how would I implement it? Because, as I know, whenever the program is closed, everything is lost. How would I implement the functionality to save all user input and keep it in memory even when the program is closed?

Comment: Something like https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json will probably work for you. Have a go with that, and then show us your code if you can't make it work.

Comment: @TomDalton So you recommend using `json`?

Comment: I have no idea what your data really looks like, but from the details you've given it sounds like it would be fine. I'm guessing the user input you want to save is just going to be text/strings?